# one sed diff result:sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

here r 2 file

--------------file a--------------

```
1,2,3
2,xx,yy
3,lllll,ddd
```

------------file b---------------

```
8,55
9,555
100,5555
```

---

result i want is :
file a-------------

```
8,2,3
9,xx,yy
100,lllll,ddd
```

so bash is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 3)
do
q=`awk -v aa=$i -F , 'NR==aa{print $1}' a`
qq=`awk -v aa=$i -F , 'NR==aa{print $1}' b`
sed -i "s/^$q/$qq/g" a 
done
```

here is no error

but error occur if :

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in $(seq 3)
do
q=`awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} NF!=1{print $1}' a`
qq=`awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} NF!=1{print $1}' b`
sed -i "s/^$q/$qq/g" a
done
```

---

here is error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command

how this error occurs?

---

THX to @EdMorton q has 3 lines when awk execute ,so sed occurs error.
q should split to execute sed,so

```
#! /bin/bash
q=`awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {print $1}' a`
qq=`awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {print $1}' b`
for ((i=1;i<=3;++i))
do
    a=`echo $q | cut -d" " -f $i`
    aa=`echo $qq | cut -d" " -f $i`
    sed -i "s/^$a/$aa/g" a
    echo $a
done
```

so the error disappear
i use cut here to split q into 3 fields
but its redundant
and THX to @user000001 ,the answer is clear
**but if every file's fields and rows are different,paste is not suitable

```
#! /bin/bash
so i vi a bash:
len1=`awk -v x=1 -F, '{if(NR>x){x=NR}}END{print x}' a`
len2=`awk -v x=1 -F, '{if(NR>x){x=NR}}END{print x}' b`
if ((len1>len2))
then
        ((yy=2*len2))

else
        ((yy=len1+len2))
fi
q=`awk -v begin="$len2" -v end="$yy"  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";ORS="\n";}{if(NR<=end-begin)  {arr[FNR]=$1;next}else if(NR>begin&&NR<=end){$1=arrFNR];print $0}}' b a`
echo $q
```

---

BTW,if result of the above bash :
8,2,3,7,4 9,xx,yy 100,lllll,ddd 1000,aloha,ee
without "\n" why?

---

@EdMorton what about more than 2 files(or i dont know how many files i have):

----file a-------------file b-----------file c---------

1,2,3,4,7--------------8,55-------------99,3$

2,xx,yyd---------------9,5555-----------999,43

3,lllll,ddd------------100,5555---------9999,533

4,aloha,ee----------1000,77

-----------------------10000,567

*******result i want is :

----file a---------------file b-----------file c---------

8,2,3,4,7--------------99,55-------------99,3$

9,xx,yyd---------------999,5555----------999,43

100,lllll,ddd----------9999,5555---------9999,533

1000,aloha,ee--------1000,77

-----------------------10000,567

waht is the shortest bash/awk/...  commands?

Comment: ...as an aside, `seq` is a nonstandard tool. If your shell is bash, use `for ((i=0; i<4; i++)); do` instead of `for i in $(seq 4); do`. This is also faster, as it doesn't involve a subprocess.

Answer (score 3):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next} {$1=a[FNR]} 1' b a
8,2,3
9,xx,yy
100,lllll,ddd
```

When you use sed with double quotes you are inviting nasal demons because the shell variables within the script get expanded before sed executes so any characters stored in those variables become part of your script. Awk, when used correctly, does not have that issue. The awk commands used in your second script produce multi-line output so sed sees the newlines and chokes.

Comment: THX,what is the last command 1 mean?and,what about more than 2 files?    NR and FNR is not enough

Comment: `1` is a true condition and so it invokes the default action of printing the current record. It's functionally the same as `{print $0}`. I don't know what you mean by `what about more than 2 files?`. If your real problem isn't captured by the sample input you posted in your question, update your question to be more truly representative of your real problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of awk, you can use `cut` and `paste`. For example:

```
$ paste -d, <(cut -d, -f 1 fileb) <(cut -d, -f 2- filea) 
8,2,3
9,xx,yy
100,lllll,ddd
```

gives the result you want.

Comment: `paste -d, file2 file1 | cut -d, -f1,4,5` is one less subprocess and isn't limited to newer version of bash.

Comment: The difference between the two is what happens when the number of columns in `filea` is unknown, but yeah, this one looks cleaner.

Comment: @user2764638 Probably some special character in the variables. could you `echo "s/^$q/$qq/g"` Instead of the sed command?

Comment: The error is because the awk commands used in his second script are going to print $1 for every line in each file, so q and qq both get multi-line values so sed chokes on the newlines.

Comment: @user000001 excute once in loop echo $q output all $1:1\n2\n3\n,why,loop has not done yet?and why the 1st bash is expected?

Comment: @Hades Basically it is what EdMorton said. In the first case there are no newlines in the variable, so it works as expected. In the second case, the newlines terminate the `sed` command before reaching the end of the `s` command, so you get ```sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command```. I still think that using `cut` and `paste` is a better option in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A single call to `awk` will do the trick:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2FS$3;next}{print $1,a[FNR]}' FS=, OFS=, file1 file2
8,2,3
9,xx,yy
100,lllll,ddd
```